# Android DialogBox issue, no getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to make a custom dialogue box, the XML seen below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/note_dialog_layout"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/note_image"
        android:src="@drawable/empty_note"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Note: C"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/note_classification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_image"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_image"
        android:id="@+id/classification_add"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/note_classification"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_image"
        android:id="@+id/classification_minus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/note_classification"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Octave: 4"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/note_octave"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_classification"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_classification"
        android:id="@+id/octave_add"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/note_octave"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_classification"
        android:id="@+id/octave_minus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/note_octave"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="SHARP"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flat_toggle"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/flat_toggle"
        android:id="@+id/sharp_toggle"
        android:background="@color/unselected"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_octave"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="FLAT"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/flat_toggle"
        android:background="@color/unselected"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_octave"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="DOTTED"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/dotted_toggle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flat_toggle"
        android:background="@color/unselected"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note_octave"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/flat_toggle" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="CROCHET"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/note_duration"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flat_toggle"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flat_toggle"
        android:id="@+id/duration_add"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/note_duration"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/note_duration"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flat_toggle"
        android:id="@+id/duration_minus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/note_duration"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/note_duration"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I've created a class that extends AppCompatDialogFragment as seen below:

```
package com.example.song2sheet;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;

public class NoteDialogBox extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_dialog_layout, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(view).setTitle("Edit Note")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        saveInput();
                    }
                });

        return dialogBuilder.create();
    }
    private void saveInput(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not yet implemented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and so I'm trying to show it using the following

```
private void openNoteDialog(int posInArray){
        NoteDialogBox dialogBox = new NoteDialogBox();
        dialogBox.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Title");
    }
```

but the `getSupportFragmentManager()` is red with the error message *cannot resolve getSupportFragmentManager()*

Have I forgotten to implement something or import something?

Comment: did you try using Context.getSupportFragmentManager() and use Activity as context..

Answer (score 1):

Let me know, where are you using `getSupportFragmentManager()` ? I mean in activity or fragment.
If you are using Activity then please try this `getSupportFragmentManager()` in Activity.
And if you are using fragment then please try this `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: It's in an adapter class as I've selected from a list. So for all intense and purpose, I guess the activity.

Comment: I worked it out. To get access to the fragment manager, I made it so that I passed l the fragment manager through when creating the adapter then stored it globally until I needed it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the appropriate `FragmentManager` depending on your case:

- If you are trying to access it inside an `Activity`, then you should use:
  `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()` (you should always use the first one!).
- If you are trying to access it inside a `Fragment` then you should use:
  `getChildFragmentManager()`. This is the private Manager of the fragment you are calling it from.
- You cannot access a `FragmentManager` from classes other than `Activity` or `Fragment`, but if you MUST for some reason, then you can get a reference to an Activity or Fragment and use the above two methods.

Comment: I'm trying to access it in a RecyclerAdapter, because, ya know, recyclerView, this is obviously not the activity. So would I have to do ```Activity.getSupportFragmentManager```? Edit: It didn't like this as getSupportFragmentManager is not static but the actual class obviously is.

Comment: I worked it out. To get access to the fragment manager, I made it so that I passed l the fragment manager through when creating the adapter then stored it globally until I needed it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I worked it out. Because I was trying to create a dialogue box in a recycler adapter, I had to pass through the FragmentManager though in the class constructor.